# Is AMF3 protocol is good for flash/flex client server development?

Tags: actionscript-3, protocols, amf, port80

I need to develop client server application that involve gaming. I have no experience in flash and I was reading about the AMF3 protocol that is compact and fast, is it better than xml/json for data exchange? Also I need it to be on port 80.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [blazeDS](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/blazeds/BlazeDS), [AMFPHP](http://amfphp.sourceforge.net/) or any other AMF-ish flavor. They have one for [ruby](http://github.com/victorcoder/rubyamf_plugin), [python](http://www.pyamf.org/index.html), different versions for php that work with [zend](http://framework.zend.com/download/amf), [cakePHP](https://trac.cakefoundation.org/amf/). Just depends on what you are comfortable with. AMFPHP is pretty simple and what I have used in the past, the new [ZendAMF is prepackaged with Flash Builder 4](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flashbuilder4_php_part2.html). AMF is the fastest way to work with data between flash and the server. It is a compressed binary. In the time it takes to send 5,000 rows of xml data you could send 20,000+ in AMF with no need to parse.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to look at [BlazeDS](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/blazeds/BlazeDS/).  It has built in AMF channels.  We use BlazeDS in all our client/server apps and prefer it over xml/json.  However, it will require a tomcat server.  Fortunately, the [turnkey edition](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/blazeds/Release+Builds) comes bundled with a pre-configured tomcat setup.

Comment: It's more efficient than xml and comparable to JSON but what we like about it is it blends so seamlessly into Adobe's suite of products that it makes life easier. We use BlazeDS to manage push messaging from our servers.  Meaning, we have one compact, efficient object that we send from our java server to our RIA clients, all over an AMF channel.

Comment: For a more detailed review of AMF vs. JSON, check [AMF vs. JSON vs. XML](http://insideria.com/2008/09/amf-vs-json-vs-xml.html) and [Clearing the FUD on amfphp’s speed versus JSON and XML ](http://www.5etdemi.com/blog/archives/2006/12/clearing-the-fud-on-amfphps-speed-versus-json-and-xml/).